# Inconsistent behavior with comparisons

Tags: python-3.x, comparison

As you can see in this snippet:

```
>>> from math import nan
>>> a = nan
>>> a == nan
False
>>> a is nan
True
>>> a = None
>>> a == None
True
>>> a is None
True
```

Comparing `nan` and comparing `None` is a different business. Why is that?

Comment: `nan==nan
Out[294]: False` Probably because of that

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27616824/python-equality-for-nan-in-a-list